# Index was out of range. GridView Giving Wrong Row Count within LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView within a LoginView that I am running into this issue when I click the edit button.  I know that I need to use `FindControl` to get to the objects within the `LoginView` so I have done that.  But now I am having this `IndexOutOfRangeException` error.  I posted the index and the `DataKeys.Count` to an error label and I don't see the issue.  But it comes up in the `xx.Rows[e.RowIndex]` only.  If I only use `e.RowIndex` (for example: `int index = e.RowIndex.ToString();`) I won't get the same error.  So I have it narrowed down to that but cannot figure it out from here.  If you need for me to post any other parts of the code please let me know.

The line giving me fits is the GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex]; line.

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = ReviewLoginView.FindControl("gvReview") as GridView;
    if (gv.DataKeys.Count > e.RowIndex)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        string Id = (row.FindControl("lblID") as Label).Text;

        string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnection"];
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("cardReview"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using paging?

Comment: I'm not using paging.  I have tried to look at the other answers on here but none of them have fixed my issue.  Are there any known quirks about using GridViews within LoginViews?

Comment: What if you use `gv.Rows.Count` instead of `gv.DataKeys.Count`. It looks like there is a difference between them.

Comment: Changing to gv.Rows.Count will make the code at least not fire.  It is as if the gv.Rows[e.RowIndex] is returning a -1 for some reason but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Just had the gv.Rows.Count display in an error label and it is always 0.  So the GridView is not getting the correct number of rows for some reason.

Comment: You should convert this line `GridView gv = ReviewLoginView.FindControl("gvReview") as GridView;` to `GridView gv = sender as GridView;`